# The paths Format is not supported exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-worker-roles, azure-diagnostics

I just installed Windowsazure SDK 1.5 and respective tools for Visualstudio 2010. But when i run the compute emulator it gives me the following exception:

> Encountered an unexpected error The given path's format is not supported.    at
> System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
>    at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
>    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionA
> ccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean check
> ForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>    at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess
> access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
>    at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Utility.SDKPaths.get_CSRunStateDirectory()
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric..ctor()
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.get_DF()
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.DevFabric(DFComma
> nds acts)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.ParseArguments(St
> ring[] args, Boolean doActions)
>    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.ExecuteActions(St
> ring[] args).

What is the fix for this weird exception?

Comment: Do you have the path that it is trying to parse?  What directory did you install the tools to?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.5 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was I had an environment variable that has some invalid location and when trying to parse compute emulator is failed.